Cant't acess pages using tomcat in diferent devices
I am using Tomcat to host my app. On the machine where I am running the app, it works properly when I enter my website at localhost:8080/app. However, when I try to access it from another computer or mobile device, I can only access the Tomcat server. When I try to open a page that exist, it creates an empty HTML page with nothing on it. If I go to a URL that doesn't exist, Tomcat gives me a 404 error.
I am trying to fix this to use in my Android Studio emulator, but it returns the same result as when I use another device on the same network.
Alrealy change the server.xml settings to this
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useIPVHosts="true"
           address="0.0.0.0"/>

